# What's the JSON schema for default Spring error responses?

Tags: java, swagger-ui, openapi, bean-validation, springdoc

I'm generating an OpenAPI definition using the springdoc library and I would like to describe the response types of default exceptions that are thrown deep in some service.

In particular there is a standard error response returned when `ResponseStatusException` exceptions are thrown and they produce this JSON:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-02-23T17:56:20.523+00:00",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "The user provides contradictory organization information",
  "path": "/api/vehicles"
}
```

I haven't found a single class that implements these fields and suspect that these fields are simply added one by one to the response.

An even more complex error response are validation responses. I didn't find a class describing these errors either:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-02-23T17:58:09.662+00:00",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Validation failed for object='addVehicleDto'. Error count: 1",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "Pattern.addVehicleDto.licensePlate",
        "Pattern.licensePlate",
        "Pattern.java.lang.String",
        "Pattern"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "addVehicleDto.licensePlate",
            "licensePlate"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "licensePlate",
          "code": "licensePlate"
        },
        [],
        {
          "defaultMessage": "^[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,3} [A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,2} [1-9][0-9]{0,3}[E]?$",
          "arguments": null,
          "codes": [
            "^[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,3} [A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,2} [1-9][0-9]{0,3}[E]?$"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "must match \"^[A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,3} [A-ZÖÜÄ]{1,2} [1-9][0-9]{0,3}[E]?$\"",
      "objectName": "addVehicleDto",
      "field": "licensePlate",
      "rejectedValue": "1",
      "bindingFailure": false,
      "code": "Pattern"
    }
  ],
  "path": "/api/vehicles"
}
```

I've modeled the "standard" error response myself and added the following annotation, but I'm unsure what `implementation` I can use for the validation errors. Those I would probably add with `Scheme.oneOf` for 400 requests.

```
  @PostMapping
  @ResponseStatus(ACCEPTED)
  @Operation(summary = "Add vehicle",
      responses = {
          @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "The user provides contradictory organization information",
              content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ResponseStatusExceptionResponse.class))),
          @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "The user is not allowed to add vehicles")}
  )
  public CompletableFuture<UUID> add
```

Comment: *"suspect that these fields are simply added one by one to the response"* Almost correct, except they are added to a `Map` and the response is generated from that `Map`.

Comment: Closes as duplicate. Although the duplicate does directly answer the question, it shows that the response is generated from a `Map`, which explains why there is no "class that implements these fields".